# Adding/changing attributes of HTML elements in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

Having issues with M$ and IE9, changing or adding attributes to HTML elements in my DOM. I have seen that this browser requires different syntax but not sure what to write I have tried the following approaches

```
var element = document.getElementById("object");
var element2 = document.getElementsByTagName("object")[0];

element.style = "something";
element.setAttribute("style","something");

element2.style = "something";
element2.setAttribute("style","something");
```

I have tried mixing and matching but I always get the following "Unable to get value of the property (whatever follows the "."): object is null or undefined"

In the html the element is just a div like

```
<div id="object"></div>
```

any ideas?

Comment: do you mean, `element.style.cssText` or `element.style.something` instead of just `element.style`

Comment: @JayHarris the something refers to the value ie <div style="width 600px">

Comment: then use `element.style.cssText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `cssText` method to change the style of multiple properties

```
element.style.cssText = "width: 600px; height: 600px; color: red;";
```

or if your just changing one use that properties method

```
element.style.width = '600px';
```

Comment: it is kicking out the error SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined not sure why? It seems like a simple task

Comment: well that means your `elements` and `elements2` are undefined

Comment: setAttribute("style.cssText" , "margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:1400px; height:900px;"); worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At what line did you get the error? document.getElementsByTagName returns an array, you should index it and then call setAttribute/style.

Comment: Updated the type, the error occurs when I acturally try and set the value of the style element.